# Ordering results using whereIn()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am selecting product by 'whereIn()' with array as parameter:

For example:

```
$parent_ids = array(3, 8, 12);
Product::whereIn('parent_id', $parent_ids)->get();
```

In results can one value parent_id have many products.

Is possible order results in eloquent like this? (group products with same parent_id and return only one product from each group around - if are results)

Result rows:

```
 parent_id=3
 parent_id=8
 parent_id=12
 parent_id=3
 parent_id=8
 parent_id=12
```

Or only 'myself' solution - GROUP BY + PHP + foreach?

Comment: you could use the `groupBy()` function and group by parent id

Comment: How can `groupBy()` help to return rows as I writted?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
Product::whereIn('parent_id', $parent_ids)->get()->unique();
```